# How to create a smart capture that creates a record in salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, smart-capture

To create a salesforce record using smart capture, should I use only AMPscript? And where can I insert an AMPscript to run when the user clicks submit on my form?

Comment: By 'Salesforce' do you mean Marketing Cloud, or Sales/Service Cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked inti using Web Collect DEManager instead? It can add new records directly to a Data Extension from a form.